# Placement new plus destructor and simple value initialization noexcept semantic

Tags: c++, c++11, semantics, type-traits, noexcept

Can one assume in unevaluated context, that `(::new (std::declval< void * >()) T())->~T()` is semantically (in sense of `noexcept`, but not in sense of type of expression) equivalent to simple `T()`? Assume that neither global, nor class-scope `operator new` are overloaded, if it mutters much.

Often in type traits `T()` used inside operator `noexcept()` to determine whether only the separate constructor is `noexcept` or not. Surely it is wrong.

To prevent the loss of generality one can assume that `T()` here is either a calling of a default constructor or of any other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Can one assume in unevaluated context, that `(::new (std::declval<
>   void * >()) T())->~T()` is semantically full equivalent to simple
>   `T()`?

Nope, The last expression there is a destructor function, which is implicitly a `void` return type.

```
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

struct T{int x; double y; };
int main(){
    constexpr int size = sizeof((::new (std::declval< void * >()) T())->~T());
}
```

The compiler should complain of trying to get the `sizeof` a `void`

Comment: Fair. My mistake. I want to consider only `noexcept` sense. Please allow me to edit the question.